# s3 upload, 400 response, no body

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

We've been using the PHP s3 SDK to upload files to s3 for over  year now and things have been working swimmingly.  Yesterday we started getting 400s intermittently while uploading files.  We retry 3 times and pause 5 seconds between tries.

In many cases the retries work, but not always.  The 400 we receive from S3 (it's a US standard bucket) have an empty body, so I have no idea where to being in fixing the problem.

We've tried syncing the clock on the machine, as that sometimes causes issues if the clock drifts, but that didn't help either.

Here is a dump of a CFResponse we got back for an error:

```
S3CFResponse::__set_state(array(
   'header' => 
  array (
    'date' => 'Sun, 24 Nov 2013 21:44:09 GMT',
    'server' => 'AmazonS3',
    'connection' => 'keep-alive',
    'transfer-encoding' => 'chunked',
    '_info' => 
    array (
      'url' => 'https://REDACTED',
      'content_type' => NULL,
      'http_code' => 400,
      'header_size' => 135,
      'request_size' => 874,
      'filetime' => -1,
      'ssl_verify_result' => 0,
      'redirect_count' => 0,
      'total_time' => 0.350825,
      'namelookup_time' => 3.0E-5,
      'connect_time' => 0.086817,
      'pretransfer_time' => 0.263472,
      'size_upload' => 0,
      'size_download' => 0,
      'speed_download' => 0,
      'speed_upload' => 0,
      'download_content_length' => -1,
      'upload_content_length' => 1959,
      'starttransfer_time' => 0.350749,
      'redirect_time' => 0,
      'certinfo' => 
            array (
      ),
      'method' => 'PUT',
    ),
    'x-aws-request-url' => 'REDACTED',
    'x-aws-redirects' => 0,
    'x-aws-stringtosign' => 'PUT

image/jpeg
Sun, 24 Nov 2013 21:44:09 GMT
x-amz-acl:private
REDACTED',
    'x-aws-requestheaders' => 
    array (
      'Content-Length' => '1959',
      'Content-Type' => 'image/jpeg',
      'Date' => 'Sun, 24 Nov 2013 21:44:09 GMT',
      'Expect' => '100-continue',
      'x-amz-acl' => 'private',
      'Authorization' => 'AWS REDACTED',
    ),
  ),
   'body' => false,
   'status' => 400,
))).
```

Comment: I'd call the lack of a body on a 400 error strange, but stranger still is why this request appears to be using chunked transfer-encoding, if this is true: http://aws.amazon.com/articles/1109#14

Comment: We're using 1.5.9 of https://github.com/amazonwebservices/aws-sdk-for-php.  It seems that this repo is out of date and that there's a new composer package that is being recommended we use instead.  Is it possible this would solve the issue?  It's just weird that it started happening less than 24 hours ago, out of the blue.

Comment: Is it still happening? Seems odd, and may just be a fluke. Either way, I'd recommend updating to version 2.x of the SDK at some point.

Comment: Yes, it's still happening, albeit intermittently.  The files do get uploaded after the 4th try when this happens.  It's weird that it would just happen out of the blue starting Saturday (11/23)