# Salesforce to Amazon S3 - Intermittent transmission failures - Invalid URI

Tags: web-services, rest, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, salesforce

I have an existing salesforce implementation that uses web services to upload attachments into a Amazon S3 bucket. This process has been working properly for the last 2 years or so. Now, quite suddenly, we are getting intermittent failures in this system (the system is only used 4 times a year, so it may have been broken for some time). I've looked into it quite a bit, and I'm at a total loss.

The system generates PutObjectInline requests through the S3 Soap API. It may generate several hundred requests over the period that it runs (usually 10-15 minutes). Of the requests made, about 50% fail (more on this below). Each failure is given a HTTP 400 status from the server with the message "Invalid URI". The body of the response is blank. Successful transmissions use the same URI as the failures. The entire transmission set is being uploaded into the same bucket.

The failures form an odd pattern, from the look of it, every other (pass, fail, pass, fail) transmission is failing, with occasional chains of 3-4 transmissions succeeding. I looked into the idea that we might be transmitting the data too quickly, but AWS has a very specific code for that: 503. Also the error itself seems to point to a connection issue of some kind.
Does anyone know what would cause this kind of issue?

This is an example of one of the failed requests (I've sripped out some of the information to save space and protect privacy):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<env:Envelope xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:env="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><env:Header/>
    <env:Body>
        <PutObjectInline xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
            <Bucket>2013-2014.(Numeric&TextValue).(TextValue)</Bucket>
            <Key>(Numerical/Text Value).2013-2014.(Text).(Number).(Text may include ' or .).(Number).(Text XXX-XXX).pdf</Key>
            <Data>(base64 encoded pdf file)</Data>
            <ContentLength>(usually in the 15-19k byte range)</ContentLength>
        <AccessControlList>
                <Grant>
                    <Grantee xsi:type="Group">
                            <URI>http://acs.amazonaws.com/groups/global/AllUsers</URI>
                    </Grantee>
                    <Permission>READ</Permission>
                </Grant>
                <Grant>
                    <Grantee xsi:type="CanonicalUser">
                        <ID>(removed)</ID>
                    </Grantee>
                    <Permission>FULL_CONTROL</Permission>
                </Grant>
            </AccessControlList>
            <AWSAccessKeyId>(removed)</AWSAccessKeyId>
            <Timestamp>2013-11-20T20:51:56.212Z</Timestamp>
            <Signature>(removed - but assume this is valid)</Signature>
            <Credential>(removed)</Credential>
        </PutObjectInline>
    </env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you are not the only one having the same problem. This reported yesterday, also getting 400 errors with no body in the response.

[s3 upload, 400 response, no body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20181771/s3-upload-400-response-no-body)